# POSTING a custom object with Retrofit2 issue

Tags: android, post, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I'm currently making my first custom Android app for a project and I can't resolve the following issue. (I made a lot of research but didn't find anything like this)

```
2020-02-15 11:41:30.075 10337-10337/com.example.quickmatch I/SigninFragmentViewModel: Required value 'surname' missing at $post
```

I'm trying to post this custom object to my backend server online :

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class PlayerObject(
        val id : Int?,
        @Json(name = "surname") val surname : String,
        @Json(name = "first_name") val firstName : String,
        val pseudo : String,
        @Json(name = "mdp") val password : String,
        @Json(name = "mail_address") val mailAddress : String,
        @Json(name = "phone_number") val phoneNumber : String?,
        @Json(name = "scored_goals") val scoredGoals : Int,
        @Json(name = "conceded_goals") val concededGoals : Int,
        @Json(name = "matches_played") val matchesPlayed : Int,
        val victories : Int,
        val avatar : String?,
        val bio : String?
)
```

I'm using Retrofit2 and Moshi with coroutines :

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0"
```

Here is my Retrofit instance :

```
/* Create Moshi object which will parse the responses */
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()

/* Retrofit builder with converter for response and base url */
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
```

To send my POST request I made this method (It should send me back the player created if successful) :

```
@POST("...")
fun addPlayer(@Body player: PlayerObject) : Deferred<PlayerObject>
```

And I call it passing this Object :

```
var newPlayerObject = PlayerObject(null, name, firstName, pseudo, password, mailAddress, phoneNumber, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null )
```

I am getting the non-null values from EditTexts with a basic `binding.editText.text.toString()`
The big problem is that I logged every value (name, surname, etc...) both in my ViewModel before the request and in my UI in the button `onClickListener` that triggers the ViewModel and everything looks fine and matches what I type in the Edits but when the app posts it seems that every attribute of the object is set to null. Since `surname` is not nullable I get the previous error. I tried to make it nullable and it is the same issue with the next attributes.
Also note that passing an object with every attribute null works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue. The problem was created by the `phone_number` field which I wanted to be optional. Indeed, when the corresponding EditText was empty when posting, the value wasn't put to `null` but something "empty" (not just ""), that explain the parsing error. So I just added a condition to set this field at `null` if the EditText isn't filled.

Answer (score 0):

I've found specifying [use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) helpful for fields in a Kotlin data class.

What happens if you try modifying your annotations to the following format?

`@field:Json(name = "surname") val surname : String`

Comment: Hi , I gave this a try but I still have the same issue unfortunatly

Comment: Are you able to share the lines of code where you build your Retrofit/OkHttp instance?

Comment: Retrofit supports coroutines since v2.6.0. Are you to update your dependency to the most recent v2.7.1? Then, you also wouldn't need Jake's `retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter` at all.

Comment: Hi, I changed my code to work with Retrofit2 2.6.0 update (2.7.1 now) by removing the call adapter dependency, removing the `Deferred` everywhere and adding `suspend` before my API functions. It works the same as before and I still have the error with the missing required value